# how do you open two tkinter Windows one after the other.?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am fairly new to python programming with its concept of class which is very different of languages like java, c++, c# ... and also the Tkinter library. I am trying to do something basic. First creating a frame that will allow the user to enter a string value; store that string value in memory then exit that frame. Creating a new file browser that will allow you to select a specific file then rename the chosen file with the string stored in memory earlier. I do not have any specific snippet of code to do that but I have two pieces of codes that could be combined to give me the result I want.

```
enter code here
# This is the snippet for the input user
def printtext():
    global e
    string = e.get() 
    return string   

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root,text='okay',command=printtext)

b.pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()

# This is for the file browser

import Tkinter,tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with asksaveasfilename like in this example.But if you want to use file_path=askopenfilename with entry, than you would have to use OS library, with function os.rename (i think) .This code is written in python 3 so if you are using python2 than just change names of libraries.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Name')
    #e = Entry(root)
    #e.pack()

    #e.focus_set()
    b = Button(root,text='okay',command= lambda:printtext(e))    
    b.pack(side='bottom')

    root.mainloop()

def printtext(e):
    #string = e.get() 
    #print(string)
    file = fd.asksaveasfile(title='Choose a file')
    #print(file)

main()
```